# Parse PFQueryTableViewController loadobjects issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am using PFQueryTableViewController in my Parse iOS project.

I call [self loadobjects] in viewWillAppear of my list view to refresh the data after returning from a detail view that allows editing of the data. This works as expected except that my TableView separator lines disappear in the list view. I have also tried putting loadobjects in viewDidAppear with same issue. The issue seems to be intermittent. Sometimes the seperator lines appear and sometimes they disappear.

Has anyone else experienced this and If so how did you resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you are not calling `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` somewhere? Did it work before you called `loadObjects`?

Comment: I have the seperator style set to default in storyboard and not turning it off in code anywhere. It only becomes an issue when I call loadObjects.

Comment: Had some other weird problems with the `loadObjects` method, seems like parse changed the implementation of it ...
Maybe you could use your own method or even your own tableviewcontroller? Or maybe someone knows this problem and can come up with an answer...